# What does this statement //! [number] mean?

Tags: c++

I have seen In many project some programmers use `//! [1]`, `//! [2]`, ..., `//! [n]` in their code but I have no idea what this could mean.

I’ll be grateful if someone point out the use of those comments.
this is a snipe code:

```
BlockingClient::BlockingClient(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    hostLabel = new QLabel(tr("&Server name:"));
    portLabel = new QLabel(tr("S&erver port:"));


    QString ipAddress;
    QList<QHostAddress> ipAddressesList = QNetworkInterface::allAddresses();
    // use the first non-localhost IPv4 address
    for (int i = 0; i < ipAddressesList.size(); ++i) {
    }
    // if we did not find one, use IPv4 localhost
    if (ipAddress.isEmpty())
        ipAddress = QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost).toString();

    //...
    connect(hostLineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
            this, SLOT(enableGetFortuneButton()));
    connect(portLineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
            this, SLOT(enableGetFortuneButton()));
//! [0]
    connect(&thread, SIGNAL(newFortune(QString)),
            this, SLOT(showFortune(QString)));
//! [0] //! [1]
    connect(&thread, SIGNAL(error(int,QString)),
            this, SLOT(displayError(int,QString)));
//! [1]

    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(hostLabel, 0, 0);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Blocking Fortune Client"));
    portLineEdit->setFocus();
}

//! [2]
void BlockingClient::requestNewFortune()
{

    getFortuneButton->setEnabled(false);
    thread.requestNewFortune(hostLineEdit->text(),
                             portLineEdit->text().toInt());
}
//! [2]

//! [3]
void BlockingClient::showFortune(const QString &nextFortune)
{
    if (nextFortune == currentFortune) {
        requestNewFortune();
        return;
    }
//! [3]

//! [4]
    currentFortune = nextFortune;
    statusLabel->setText(currentFortune);
    getFortuneButton->setEnabled(true);
}
//! [4]
```

Comment: Looks like doxygen doc comments of some sort.

Comment: Can you give an example of a project that you have seen this done?

Comment: That the triforce of coding.

Comment: When I wonder what my collegues write I *ask* them. Have you asked your collegues who wrote the code why they put it there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm only guessing since you don't show more complete code (or in this case more complete comment).

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is a documentation generator that parsers code declarations and comments of a specific format. If you read [this part of the manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) you will see that it recognizes `//!` as a special comment that contains documentation. Doxygen supports [markdown](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html) which have links inside square brackets.

So this is nothing related to actual code, other than to help document it. And it's certainly not a statement that the compiler will try to generate code for.

Comment: You can add that any C (99 and up) or C++ compiler will *always* recognise "//" as a comment, until the end of the line, no exceptions.

Comment: @user1695063 Looks like markup links, just the same as can be used when formatting links here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Those are merely comments. They have no special meaning in C or C++. They might have some special meaning in some other context, or they may be merely a commenting convention for that project.